# How to store single $_SESSION variable in the database?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, session

I use WordPress. I need to store country preference in a session variable. I prefer to store it in the database and delete the entry if the user is inactive for 30 minutes. I was referring to some tutorials on how to store session variables in a DB. By overriding the following function, how can I make sure that I am doing this only for my session variables and not for the WordPress session variables?

```
session_set_save_handler(
  array($this, "_open"),
  array($this, "_close"),
  array($this, "_read"),
  array($this, "_write"),
  array($this, "_destroy"),
  array($this, "_gc")
);
```

Comment: Add you custom code to the `_write` function you claim to use for storage there.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your own implementation of `SessionHandlerInterface` as mentioned in [php tutorials](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). Then in your custom session class you must define your own implementation of main methods like `open`, `read`, `write`. There will no be conflict with Wordpress, because it's not using sessions for storing information. It only uses cookies. Btw, why don't you want to use cookie too?